# Unable to run virtual machine in Android Studio

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, virtual-machine

When I try to run a virtual device in Android Studio, I get the error:

> Enable VT-x in your BIOS settings, ensure that your linux distro has a
>   working KVM module.

I'm using an HP Probook 440 dual booted with Ubuntu and Windows 10. I can't seem to find an option to enable VT-x on my system. I was able to run a virtual device on Eclipse in Windows 10, but I get this error when I try to create a virtual device in my Android Studio in Ubuntu.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my HP Probook 450, so I guess with 440 the solution should be similar.

Restart the Notebook and keep tapping F10 key during the startup to access the BIOS. Once you get to the BIOS please select System Configuration and then go to Device Configuration. Now here you need to look for either BIOS Virtualisation or VT-X and enable the same.

Comment: does this mess up the dual boot in any way?

Comment: @user8437000 - I don't know. However, I don't think it has anything to do with the dual boot

Comment: @user8437000 no it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

While your system is starting up

- press `esc` to bring up boot options
- press `F10` to go to the BIOS menu
- Go to 'System Configuration' tab
- Select 'Virtualization Technology`
- Select 'Enabled'
- Exit **saving changes**

[image]

Comment: will this mess up the dual boot in any way?

Comment: no it won't, virtualization will work on both ubuntu and win 10

Comment: @user8437000 did this solve your problem? and if it did, accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using Oracle's Virtual Box and Ubuntu. Managed to get Android Studio's emulator to work fine with Fedora 27 running on VMWare Workstation 14 player on a Windows 7 machine with an i7 CPU.